# Randomly generate 1 and 0 as a queue

Tags: java, random, queue

I want my program to randomly generate 1 and 0 but it should look like it's in a queue. The 1 is represented by a person and 0 means that there's no person. It should generate random 1 and 0 like this `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1`, if the line is in the left and vice versa if it's in the right, not like this `1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1`.

```
public void randPeople(){
    int person1 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    int person2 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    int person3 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    int person4 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    int person5 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    int person6 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    int person7 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    int person8 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    int person9 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    int person10 = rand.nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0;

    EntryFloor1.setText(Integer.toString(person1) + " " + Integer.toString(person2) + " " + 
                           Integer.toString(person3) + " " + Integer.toString(person4) + " " + 
                           Integer.toString(person5) + " " + Integer.toString(person6) + " " + 
                           Integer.toString(person7) + " " + Integer.toString(person8) + " " + 
                           Integer.toString(person9) + " " + Integer.toString(person10));
}
```

Comment: Q: Isn't `rand.nextInt(8)` a queue of three zeroes and/or ones (as an example)?

Comment: @paulsm4 i tried but it has a number other than 1 or zero at the first number

Comment: Dude: the point is ... a binary "number" ... is equivalent to a *string of bits*.  If you store 0 or one in an array of "int" ... you're only using *ONE* of the *32 BITS* in each element.

Comment: @paulsm4 yes i want to use them as one because i'm creating an elevator simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want. Just as a side note - if you only care about whether or not a person exists I would suggest using boolean values to represent the people. Since you specifically said 1 and 0 I wrote the code below to produce that output. You'll notice that I do use the `nextBoolean()` method of the `Random` class as it is simpler and more readable for what I'm doing.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandPeopleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(lineUpLeft(10));
        System.out.println(lineUpRight(10));
    }

    public static List<Integer> lineUpLeft(int numPeople){
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0; i < numPeople; i++){
            boolean person = rand.nextBoolean();
            if(person){
                list.add(1);
            }
        }
        for(int i=list.size(); i < numPeople; i++){
            list.add(0);
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static List<Integer> lineUpRight(int numPeople){
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0; i < numPeople; i++){
            boolean person = rand.nextBoolean();
            if(person){
                list.add(1);
            }
        }
        for(int i=list.size(); i < numPeople; i++){
            list.add(0, 0);
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

Example output:

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

I provided the above methods to illustrate how similar aligning the people left or right can be. Here is a more generic version that uses a single method with an additional parameter to specify the alignment.

```
public static List<Integer> lineUpPeople(int numPeople, boolean alignLeft){
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0; i < numPeople; i++){
            boolean person = rand.nextBoolean();
            if(person){
                list.add(1);
            }
        }
        for(int i=list.size(); i < numPeople; i++){
            if(alignLeft)
                list.add(0);
            else
                list.add(0,0);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Lastly, here is another way to approach the problem. Rather than generating a random value for each potential person simply generate the number of people and then fill in the list/queue appropriately.

```
public static List<Integer> lineUp(int maxPeople, boolean alignLeft){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int numPeople = rand.nextInt(maxPeople+1);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0; i < maxPeople; i++){
            if(i < numPeople)   
                list.add(1);
            else if(alignLeft)
                list.add(0);
            else
                list.add(0,0);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: i changed the correct answer to yours given that it's more detailed and more userful in terms of queue. Thanks! :D

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Implemented a simple random function to generate 0s and 1s

```
    int[] queue = new int[10];
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = r.nextInt(queue.length);
    int r1 = 1 - rand % 2;
    int r2 = rand % 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
        if (i <= rand) {
            queue[i] = r1;
        } else {
            queue[i] = r2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Queue " + Arrays.toString(queue));
```

output

```
Queue [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

With Java8 generator

```
    final int size = 10;
    final Random random = new Random();
    boolean order = random.nextBoolean();
    Object[] arr = IntStream.generate(() -> random.nextInt(size) % 2).limit(size).boxed().sorted((i1, i2) -> order ? i1 - i2 : i2 - i1).toArray();
    System.out.println("Arrays " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

output

```
Arrays [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: welcome, you can optimize it further by not setting zeros as the array will be initialized with zero

Comment: I’d recommend setting the zeros explicitly for readability any time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Random r = new Random();

    boolean b = r.nextBoolean(); // left or right
    int l = r.nextInt(11); // breakpoint to change from 0 to 1 or other way
    System.out.println(b + " " + l);
    int person[] = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (b) {
            if (i < l)
                person[i] = 1;
            else
                person[i] = 0;

        } else {
            if (i < l)
                person[i] = 0;
            else
                person[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(person));
```